FeatureCollection (Error) User memory limit exceeded
I am trying to execute a LULC map for my region of interest and I get the Error:
stating

User memory limit exceeded.

Below is the code:
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")

var filteredL8 = ee.Image(L8.filterBounds(roi)
            .filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-08-31')
            .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than',1)
            .median()
            .clip(roi)
);

print(filteredL8);
Map.addLayer(filteredL8);

var ndvi = filteredL8.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
Map.addLayer(ndvi);

var mndwi = filteredL8.normalizedDifference(['B11', 'B3']).rename('mNDWI');
Map.addLayer(mndwi); 

var evi = filteredL8.expression(
  '2.5 * ((Nir - Red) / (Nir + 6 * Red - 7.5 * Blue + 1))', {
    'Nir' : filteredL8.select('B8'),
    'Red' : filteredL8.select('B4'),
    'Blue' : filteredL8.select('B2') 
  });
Map.addLayer(evi, {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['a6611a', 'f5f5f5', '4dac26']}, 'EVI')


function addIndices(image) {
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}

// Map the function over the collection
var withIndices = L8.map(addIndices);

// Composite
var filteredL8 = withIndices.median();
print(filteredL8);

var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI'];

var samples = Water.merge(Mangrove).merge(Vegetation).merge(Aquacultureponds).merge(Builtup).merge(BarrenLand);
print(samples);

//Training Dataset

var training = filteredL8.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection:samples, 
  properties:['Class'], 
  scale:10,
  });
  
print(training);

//80% daya for training and 20% for testing

var trainData = training.randomColumn();

var trainset = trainData.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('random',0.8));
var testset = trainData.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random',0.8));

//Classification Model

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({
  features:trainset, 
  classProperty:'Class', 
  inputProperties:bands
})

// Classify Image

var classified = filteredL8.select(bands).classify(classifier);

// Display the result

Map.addLayer(classified, {min:0, max:0.3, palette:['blue', 'red', 'green', 'pink', 'yellow', 'brown']}, 'output');


The code seems correct. It probably fails due to the fact that your ROI is too big. Try with a smaller one.
